# Access form fields inside controller's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm starting to develop a small application in Ruby On Rails. I have a short form (within a view) in which the number of fields is variable and created with the code snippet below:

```
<% for item in @event.items %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" /></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I want to after click 'submit', run a controller's method that access to the data included in each of the fields in the form and perform insertions on the database. In the end, I want the page to be refreshed.

How do I customize the action of the submit button to perform a controller's function? And how do I access inside this function to the form fields (whose number is variable as mentioned).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "local"
    t.text     "description"
    t.date     "event_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested attributes. Then it should looks something like this (sorry for HAML):

```
= form_for @event do |f|
  = f.fields_for :items do |item|
    = item.object.name  #displays item name
    = item.number :quantity
```

And in your event model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
```

I would suggest to use in this case the nested_form gem https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.